# Problem with bundle install (mysql2) on Windows machine

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails backend and try to build my project with `bundle install`

But I get an error with `mysql2`

```
Resolving dependencies...
Installing mysql2 0.5.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5/ext/mysql2
C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0 extconf.rb
checking for rb_absint_size()... yes
checking for rb_absint_singlebit_p()... yes
checking for rb_gc_mark_movable()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enc_interned_str() in ruby.h... yes
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-openssl-dir
        --without-openssl-dir
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysqlclient-dir
        --without-mysqlclient-dir
        --with-mysqlclient-include
        --without-mysqlclient-include=${mysqlclient-dir}/include
        --with-mysqlclient-lib
        --without-mysqlclient-lib=${mysqlclient-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `block in find_library': undefined
method `split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

    paths = paths.flat_map {|path| path.split(File::PATH_SEPARATOR)}
                                       ^^^^^^
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `flat_map'
        from C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/mkmf.rb:1083:in `find_library'
        from extconf.rb:131:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/mysql2-0.5.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.5 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/mysql2-0.5.5/gem_make.out

  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:102:in `run'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:28:in `build'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in `build_extension'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:205:in `block in
build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:202:in `each'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:202:in `build_extensions'
  C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:843:in `build_extensions'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:72:in
`build_extensions'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in
`install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:203:in
`install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in
`install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in
`install_from_spec'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:130:in
`do_install'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:121:in
`block in worker_pool'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in
`apply_func'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in
`block in process_queue'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`loop'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
`process_queue'
C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.21/lib/bundler/worker.rb:90:in
`block (2 levels) in create_threads'

An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.5.5), and Bundler cannot
continue.

In Gemfile:
  mysql2
```

I am running on a Windows machine and have MySQL Server installed.

`gem install mysql2`

Installed MySQL server

Comment: Please add the contents of C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.2.0/mysql2-0.5.5/mkmf.log to your question